# Nhibernate intelligent pre-fetching in 1 to Many Scenario

Tags: nhibernate, one-to-many, fluent, one-to-one, prefetch

We are using NHibernate 3.2 with fluent mappings.The following is a simple 1 to Many mapping in highly scalable performance sensitive system

```
    public class Root
    {
        public Root()
        {
            Childs = new List<Child>();
        }
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<Child> Childs { get; set; }
        public virtual int LastChildID { get; set; }
        public virtual int CurrentChildID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Root Root { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

When we load this from the repository in almost all cases we are only interest in the Current Child as defined by CurrentChildID and would want to read this in one hit from the database along with the root but no other Child records. If we are then interested in the remaining children we only need to load the records between LastChildID and CurrentChildID - the reason for this is we may have hundreds of children for the root and everything before the LastChildID will be marked for archiving/datawarehousing which is handled seperately.

How do we configure the pre-fetching in NHibernate. WE just cannot find an example.

Answer (score 0):

i would change the class and implement getter and setters to make them consistent adding and removing from all three properties

```
public class Root
{
    public Root()
    {
        Childs = new List<Child>();
        LastChilds = new List<Child>();
    }

    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> AllChilds { get; private set; }
    public virtual IList<Child> ActiveChilds { get; private set; }
    public virtual Child CurrentChild { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
public class RootMap : ClassMap<Root>
{
    public RootMap()
    {

        HasMany(r => r.AllChilds);

        HasMany(r => r.ActiveChilds)
            .Where("archived = false"); // the childs know if they are archived otherwise it will get more complex

        References(r => r.CurrentChild, "LastChildID")
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
```